# I call a method and it gives me an error

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, warnings

My source code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Arvore {

    public Arvore() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void inserir(String x) {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    public void remove(String x) {
        root = remove(x, root);
    }

    private No remove(String x, No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return t;
        }

        int comp = x.compareTo(t.str);

        if (comp < 0) {
            t.left = remove(x, t.left);
        } else if (comp > 0) {
            t.right = remove(x, t.right);
        } else if (t.left != null && t.right != null) {
            t.str = findMin(t.right).str;
            t.right = remove(t.str, t.right);
        } else {
            t = (t.left != null) ? t.left : t.right;
        }
        return balance(t);
    }

    public String findMin() {
        return findMin(root).str;
    }

    public String findMax() {
        return findMax(root).str;
    }

    public boolean contains(String x) {
        return contains(x, root);
    }

    public void makeEmpty() {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }
    private static final int maxBal = 1;

    private No balance(No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return t;
        }

        if (height(t.left) - height(t.right) > maxBal) {
            if (height(t.left.left) >= height(t.left.right)) {
                t = rotateWithLeftChild(t);
            } else {
                t = doubleWithLeftChild(t);
            }
        } else if (height(t.right) - height(t.left) > maxBal) {
            if (height(t.right.right) >= height(t.right.left)) {
                t = rotateWithRightChild(t);
            } else {
                t = doubleWithRightChild(t);
            }
        }

        t.height = Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right)) + 1;
        return t;
    }

    public void checkBalance() {
        checkBalance(root);
    }

    private int checkBalance(No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (t != null) {
            int hl = checkBalance(t.left);
            int hr = checkBalance(t.right);
            if (Math.abs(height(t.left) - height(t.right)) > 1
                    || height(t.left) != hl || height(t.right) != hr) {
                System.out.println("OOPS!!");
            }
        }

        return height(t);
    }

    private No insert(String x, No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return new No(x, null, null);
        }

        int comp = x.compareTo(t.str);

        if (comp < 0) {
            t.left = insert(x, t.left);
        } else if (comp > 0) {
            t.right = insert(x, t.right);
        } else
            ;

        t.occ+=1;

        return balance(t);
    }

    private No findMin(No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return t;
        }

        while (t.left != null) {
            t = t.left;
        }
        return t;
    }

    private No findMax(No t) {
        if (t == null) {
            return t;
        }

        while (t.right != null) {
            t = t.right;
        }
        return t;
    }

    private boolean contains(String x, No t) {
        while (t != null) {
            int comp = x.compareTo(t.str);

            if (comp < 0) {
                t = t.left;
            } else if (comp > 0) {
                t = t.right;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void printTree(No t) {
        if (t != null) {
            printTree(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.str + ": " + t.occ);
            printTree(t.right);
        }
    }

    private int height(No t) {
        return t == null ? -1 : t.height;
    }

    private No rotateWithLeftChild(No k2) {
        No k1 = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2;
        k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.left), height(k2.right)) + 1;
        k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.left), k2.height) + 1;
        return k1;
    }

    private No rotateWithRightChild(No k1) {
        No k2 = k1.right;
        k1.right = k2.left;
        k2.left = k1;
        k1.height = Math.max(height(k1.left), height(k1.right)) + 1;
        k2.height = Math.max(height(k2.right), k1.height) + 1;
        return k2;
    }

    private No doubleWithLeftChild(No k3) {
        k3.left = rotateWithRightChild(k3.left);
        return rotateWithLeftChild(k3);
    }

    private No doubleWithRightChild(No k1) {
        k1.right = rotateWithLeftChild(k1.right);
        return rotateWithRightChild(k1);
    }


    private class No {

        No(String tStr) {
            this(tStr, null, null);
        }

        No(String tStr, No lt, No rt) {
            str = tStr;
            left = lt;
            right = rt;
            height = 0;
            occ = 1;
        }
        String str;
        No left;
        No right;
        int height;
        int occ = 0;
    }
    private No root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arvore t = new Arvore();
        System.out.println("AVL TREE TEST\n");
        String msg;
        String[] inputs;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList palavras = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;

        while (true) {
            msg = sc.nextLine();
            if (msg.equals("")) {
                break;
            }


            inputs = msg.split(" ");

            i = 0;

            while (i < inputs.length) {
                palavras.add(inputs[i]);
            }

        }

        i = 0;
        while (i < palavras.size()) {
            if (palavras.get(i).equals("REMOVE")) {
                palavras.remove(palavras.get(i));
                palavras.remove(palavras.get(i + 1));
                i += 2;
            } else {
                t.insert(palavras.get(i));
            }
            i++;
        }




    t.printTree();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why i have an error when i call insert and printTree, on the main function. 
And i have a warning by adding a string to my arraylist, when i do `palavras.add(inputs[i])`.

Comment: Use `ArrayList<String> palavras = new ArrayList<String>()` instead to fix the warning. We can't help you with the other error if you don't explain exactly what the problem is. Also, please post only the minimum amount of code needed to analyze the problem.

Comment: i posted every code i have ...

Comment: my main problem is still there and i can't figure out why. when i do t.insert(palavras.get(i)) and printTree(), i get an error message ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop:

```
i = 0;

while (i < inputs.length) {
    palavras.add(inputs[i]);
}
```

is not incrementing `i`, so you will eventually run out of space for the array as you try to insert an infinite number of references to `inputs[0]`.

The warning is because you are using a raw `ArrayList`. Try declaring `palavras` as:

```
ArrayList<String> palavras = new ArrayList<>(); // new ArrayList<String>(); if pre Java 7
```

Your other loop:

```
i = 0;
while (i < palavras.size()) {
    if (palavras.get(i).equals("REMOVE")) {
        palavras.remove(palavras.get(i));
        palavras.remove(palavras.get(i + 1));
        i += 2;
    } else {
        t.insert(palavras.get(i));
    }
    i++;
}
```

will generate an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the first branch of the `if` is taken when `i == palavras.size() - 1` when it tries to remove the second element. Even if you are guaranteed that `"REMOVE"` is always followed by another element, you need to either reverse the order of the removals:

```
palavras.remove(palavras.get(i + 1));
palavras.remove(palavras.get(i));
```

or remove the element at `i` twice:

```
palavras.remove(palavras.get(i));
palavras.remove(palavras.get(i));
```

(because when you call `remove()` it moves all succeeding elements down one position in the array).

You are calling `t.printTree()` but, there is no such method defined in class `Arvore`; the method you did define takes a tree as an argument. Same thing with `insert()`: the actual method that's available takes a `String` and a `No` as arguments.

Comment: thanks for solving one of my problems, but my main problem is still there and i can't figure out why. when i do t.insert(palavras.get(i)) and printTree(), i get an error message ...

Comment: insert(java.lang.String,Arvore.No) in Arvore cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
                t.insert(palavras.get(i));
                 ^
printTree(Arvore.No) in Arvore cannot be applied to ()
    printTree();

Comment: @user3202895 - i addressed the two error messages you are receiving.

Comment: the problem is still there, i have absolutly no idea why

Comment: @user3202895 - Is it the same problem you started with? Perhaps you could edit your question and add the code as it looks now, together with the error message(s) you are now seeing. (If the code and the messages have changed significantly, it might be better to start a new question.)